# Use of Brown-Forsythe test

Tags: variance

I am looking at using the Brown-Forsythe test to test equality of variances for a national rate observed in four years -- is this valid to conduct a test for equality of variances, with four data points? Or does this test require that multiple data points be observed in each year, and then run the test compared across years?

Comment: I think we need more information. What do you mean by a national rate?

Comment: This is a data set where there is a national median value calculated for all states in a single year, so each year has one observation. For example, the national median performance on a measure of health (rate of obesity among adults). Is it valid to run a Brown-Forsythe test on the national median value, across 4 years to identify if there is equality of variances?

Comment: I'm still not quite getting it. States are American states, so there are 50? And the national median performance is the median of each state (so you have 50 values * 4 years because a state is a nation) or is national one value (because a nation contains states? So you have 1 value * 4 years?
I suspect that the answer is going to be no, because you have repeated data.

Comment: Thank you, there are 50 states in the nation, and it is one national value (because the 50 states comprise the US). Is running the test on 1 value*4 years valid? What is the concern related to repeated data observations between years.

Comment: Maybe put some example data in the question?